# Torrent speed slow on Android mobile device

Tags: downloading, torrents, bittorrent

I have installed [BitTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.client) on my Xperia Z. While downloading I observed that it limits speed to 100-130 kbps max. It's same for all torrents irrespective of the number of seeders.

When I tried from a laptop with same torrent and the same Wi-Fi connection, I get up to 2 MBps.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is there any app which doesnt limit speed?

Comment: I am not sure.  Please note that app recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

The free version of the BitTorrent app has limited bandwidth.  Per the description on the Pro (paid) version:

> ✔ No speed limits and no size limits